# Is this bad or good for performance if I always initialize one type of class in different classes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

world! I have an `Actions` class, where I hold all actions, animations and sound-plays in my sprite-kit game. So in all my `SKNode`, `SKScene`, `SKSpriteNode` classes I always initialize this `Actions` class. Is this good for performance? Or I have to initialize this one once, for example in `GameViewController` and then pass a copy of this class to all other classes, where I need?

Comment: You could use a factory class instead. Don't instantiate the instance. Use static funcs and vars which will dispense the action without using lots of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fogmeister has mentioned in his comment you can use static methods to achieve this. This should also help with performance.

If you check the SKAction documentation you will notice that it uses class vars and methods as well.

In general if you do not need to instantiate a class multiple times, which your case is a perfect example of, than its best to use static/class methods or Singletons.

You can either use a class, struct or enum. I prefer to use enums because you cannot instantiate them by accident or need to add a private initialiser.

```
// Class
class SKActionHelper {

     static var someProperty = ...

     static func someMethod() { 
         ... 
     }
 }

 // Struct
 struct SKActionHelper {

     static var someProperty = ...

     static func someMethod() { 
         ... 
     }
 }

 // Enum
 enum SKActionHelper {

     static var someProperty = ...

     static func someMethod() { 
         ... 
     }
 }
```

Now you can call those properties or methods anywhere in your project and do not need to instantiate the class each time.

```
 SKActionHelper.someProperty = ...
 SKActionHelper.someMethod()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for fully explaining! like it!

Comment: You are very welcome. If you could mark the answer as correct it would much appreciated. Happy coding